# Converting bitwise if condition to usual if condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, bit-manipulation

I have found this if condition using bitwise, I don't know how to convert it to work with normal logical operator.

```
if (out[currentState] & (1 << j))
```

How to provide an equivalent condition that doesn't use bitwise?

Comment: You can’t - at least not efficiently. This is testing a single bit of the data, which is best done with bitwise operators.

Comment: This is checking if the bit on position "j" is set. Why shouldn't it be a bitwise operation?

Comment: What is the range of `j` and type of `out`?  Post a [mcve]

Comment: even not efficiently, how would you provide an equivalence?

Comment: @Reinstate, http://cpp.sh/33squ, line 127

Comment: The proper way to do this is with a bitwise operation. Why would you need an equivalent that doesn't work as well, unless it's for a homework assignment?

Comment: What's wrong with bitwise operations? They much faster and easier to master, so go for it

Comment: @KenWhite right

Comment: @KenWhite This is not true. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework). However, OP should make the best effort, which is what we require from all askers.

Comment: @Amadan: From the [help]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.* None of that is contained in this question in its current state.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. I do not agree with the blanket "We don't do homework" statement, unless you meant it as "We will not do your homework for you without you doing anything" (but this is also true of a non-homework problem). But it can be interpreted as "We will not help with homework whatsoever".

Comment: @Amadan, Kenwhite, this was just basic syntax question.

Comment: Bitwise operations are not less "normal" than logical ones, they just have different purpose. So I vote to close  your question as pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bitwise operations aren't that difficult to learn, in fact they're much faster than other data type operations. However, you can use a function, to hide the complicated computation, like so:

```
 bool Check( const Foo& foo, int pos) {
     return foo & 1 << pos;

if(Check(out[currentState], j)) dosomething();
```

Comment: the function is still using bitwise operations under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Bit shifts are basically multiplications and divisions by 2. The above condition is equivalent to

```
if ((out[currentState] >> j) & 1)
```

which can be converted to

```
if ((int)(out[currentState] / pow(2, j)) % 2)
```

Comment: @user12614580 how is that related to this question?

Comment: I just want to know their equivalences too?
1- if (out[currentState] |= (1 << i)); 
2- if (out[g[state][ch]] |= out[failure]);

Comment: yes. It can be easily converted to normal math. Setting a bit to 1 is just like setting it to 0 then set it to 1 which is a `+` operation. Or add directly with the remainder modulo 2

Comment: I haven't fully got you, can you provide both of these ways, it's interesting

Comment: it's out of scope for this question. Just think about it yourself, I've already given all the hints. See also [How can bitwise operations be modeled with math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305727/90333), [bitwise operations - Mathematical equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents), [mathematical equation for AND bitwise operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199625/995714)

Comment: "It can be easily converted to normal math." question is should it? Your second statement is much less readable that the first and original. I do not criticize your answer, just want to point that it is not clear what the purpose of the action asked by OP.